# pandas groupby and get val by rank column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this pandas dataframe consists of ids, gender, names and rank.

```
+-----------------------------------+
|   ids  |   gnr  |   nms  |   rnk  |
|-----------------------------------+
|    C   |    F   |   H    |    8   |
|    A   |    F   |   Q    |    3   |
|    B   |    F   |   A    |    2   |
|    C   |    M   |   J    |    1   |
|    A   |    M   |   E    |    2   |
|    A   |    F   |   J    |    2   |
|    B   |    M   |   X    |    6   |
|    B   |    M   |   X    |    2   |
|    C   |    F   |   F    |    3   |
|    C   |    M   |   J    |    8   |
|    A   |    M   |   X    |    9   |
|    C   |    M   |   O    |    5   |
|    B   |    M   |   L    |    7   |
|    B   |    F   |   T    |    7   |
|    A   |    M   |   W    |    9   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

```
data.groupby(['ids', 'gnr'])['rnk'].nsmallest(2).reset_index().drop(columns='level_2')
```

I group them by ids, gender, and rank (get the 2 smallest in rank per gender and ids) with the following command and I got the results below

```
+--------------------------+
|   ids  |   gnr  |   rnk  |
|--------------------------|
|    A   |    M   |   2    |
|    A   |    M   |   5    |
|    A   |    F   |   2    |
|    A   |    F   |   3    |
|    B   |    M   |   2    |
|    B   |    M   |   6    |
|    B   |    F   |   2    |
|    B   |    F   |   7    |
|    C   |    M   |   1    |
|    C   |    M   |   5    |
|    C   |    F   |   3    |
|    C   |    F   |   8    |
+--------------------------+
```

I want to get that top 2 names each ids and gender using the top 2 ranks result i get from nsmallest()

something like this.

```
+-----------------------------------+
|   ids  |   gnr  |   rnk  |   nms  |
|--------------------------|--------|
|    A   |    M   |   2    |    E   |
|    A   |    M   |   5    |    W   |
|    A   |    F   |   2    |    J   |
|    A   |    F   |   3    |    Q   |
|    B   |    M   |   2    |    X   |
|    B   |    M   |   6    |    X   |
|    B   |    F   |   2    |    A   |
|    B   |    F   |   7    |    T   |
|    C   |    M   |   1    |    J   |
|    C   |    M   |   5    |    O   |
|    C   |    F   |   3    |    F   |
|    C   |    F   |   8    |    H   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Just `merge` it: `new.merge(df, how="left", on=["ids", "gnr", "rnk"])`.

Comment: Why can't you data.groupby(['ids', 'gnr', 'nms']) ['rnk'].nsmallest(2).reset_index().drop(columns='level_2') and then reorder column if necessary?

Comment: @HenryYik thank you! it solves my problem.